# Why is this code getting invalid syntax error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def compare(A: object, B: object) -> object:
    if(A>B):
        return A
    elif(A<B):
        return B
    else:
        return A


if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = int(input())
    scorelist = []

    for i in range(0,A):
        tmp = int(input())
        scorelist.append(tmp)

    sum =+ int(scorelist[0])
    k = 1
    for j in A-2:
        D = compare(scorelist[k],scorelist[k+1]
        k = scorelist.index(D)
        sum =+ D


    print (sum)
    print(scorelist)
```

`scorelist` is unresolved reference and I don't know why I cannot use "`k`".

```
   line 22
    k = scorelist.index(D)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You're missing a close brace at the end of `compare(scorelist[k],scorelist[k+1]`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's the closing parenthesis that you are missing. `compare(scorelist[k],scorelist[k+1]` should be `compare(scorelist[k],scorelist[k+1])`.

Comment: Unbalanced parentheses `:)`

Comment: http://level1wiki.wikidot.com/syntax-error lists some common syntax errors, though not this one. Someone please provide a better link if you know :)

Comment: @dani re `why can I not use k`: actually you can; what you see is **compiler** (code parser) giving you an imprecise error. This is by the nature of how they work, compiler "eats" code until it can't and then "barfs". In this case, the error is immediately before `k`. Compiler ignores whitespace, thus the error is at the end of the previous line. This is rather common, in many programming languages. Mnemonic — when compiler barfs, look at what it ate last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket:

```
def compare(A: object, B: object) -> object:
    if(A>B):
        return A
    elif(A<B):
        return B
    else:
        return A


if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = int(input())
    scorelist = []

    for i in range(0,A):
        tmp = int(input())
        scorelist.append(tmp)

    sum =+ int(scorelist[0])
    k = 1
    for j in A-2:
        D = compare(scorelist[k],scorelist[k+1])
        k = scorelist.index(D)
        sum =+ D


    print (sum)
    print(scorelist)
```